# Bluetooth BLE does not connect

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried all ways but i can't connect to the other bluetooth device. I perform these steps:

- scan devices
- stop scan when I find the device with "A-"
- connect to device

I can find all the devices but then I can't connect to the one I want. Unfortunately I can't find a complete example

This is the code I use:

````
import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BluetoothManager btManager;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    Button startScanningButton;
    Button stopScanningButton;
    TextView peripheralTextView;
    BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt;
    BluetoothDevice device;
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 2;
    private boolean mEchoInitialized;

    private static final String TAG = "ClientActivity";

//
//    private ActivityClientBinding mBinding;

    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Handler mLogHandler;
    private Map<String, BluetoothDevice> mScanResults;

    private boolean mConnected;
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback;

    public static String SERVICE_STRING = "7D2EA28A-F7BD-485A-BD9D-92AD6ECFE93E";
    public static UUID SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString(SERVICE_STRING);

    public static String CHARACTERISTIC_ECHO_STRING = "7D2EBAAD-F7BD-485A-BD9D-92AD6ECFE93E";
    public static UUID CHARACTERISTIC_ECHO_UUID = UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_ECHO_STRING);

    public static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        peripheralTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PeripheralTextView);
        peripheralTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        startScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartScanButton);
        startScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startScanning();
            }
        });

        stopScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopScanButton);
        stopScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopScanning();
            }
        });
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
        btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


        if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        // Make sure we have access coarse location enabled, if not, prompt the user to enable it
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
            builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect peripherals.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Check low energy support
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            // Get a newer device
//            logError("No LE Support.");
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
//            Log.d("ci sono",result.getDevice().getName());
            if (result.getDevice().getName() != null && result.getDevice().getName().contains("A-"))
                stopScanning();
//            peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "\n");

            // auto scroll for text view
//            final int scrollAmount = peripheralTextView.getLayout().getLineTop(peripheralTextView.getLineCount()) - peripheralTextView.getHeight();
            // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
//            if (scrollAmount > 0)
//                peripheralTextView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);

            connectDevice(result.getDevice());
//            bluetoothGatt = result.getDevice().connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, gattClientCallback);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void startScanning() {
        System.out.println("start scanning");
        peripheralTextView.setText("");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        System.out.println("stopping scanning");
        peripheralTextView.append("Stopped Scanning");
        startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    private void connectDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
//        log("Connecting to " + device.getAddress());
        GattClientCallback gattClientCallback = new GattClientCallback();
        bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattClientCallback);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        // call the superclass method first
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("spegni", "bluetooth");
        btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);

    }

    private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
//            log("onConnectionStateChange newState: " + newState);

            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
//                logError("Connection Gatt failure status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // handle anything not SUCCESS as failure
//                logError("Connection not GATT sucess status " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
                return;
            }

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
//                log("Connected to device " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                setConnected(true);
                gatt.discoverServices();
                Log.d("discoverRiuscito", "onServicesDiscovered " + status + " " + gatt.discoverServices()
                        + " " + gatt.getServices());
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
//                log("Disconnected from device");
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);


            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
//                log("Device service discovery unsuccessful, status " + status);
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics = BluetoothUtils.findCharacteristics(gatt);
            if (matchingCharacteristics.isEmpty()) {
//                logError("Unable to find characteristics.");
                return;
            }

//            log("Initializing: setting write type and enabling notification");
            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : matchingCharacteristics) {
                characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
                enableCharacteristicNotification(gatt, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
//                log("Characteristic written successfully");
            } else {
//                logError("Characteristic write unsuccessful, status: " + status);
                disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
//                log("Characteristic read successfully");
                readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            } else {
//                logError("Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);
                // Trying to read from the Time Characteristic? It doesnt have the property or permissions
                // set to allow this. Normally this would be an error and you would want to:
                // disconnectGattServer();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
//            log("Characteristic changed, " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }

        private void enableCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            boolean characteristicWriteSuccess = gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
            if (characteristicWriteSuccess) {
//                log("Characteristic notification set successfully for " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                if (BluetoothUtils.isEchoCharacteristic(characteristic)) {
                    initializeEcho();
                }
            } else {
//                logError("Characteristic notification set failure for " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            }
        }

        private void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            byte[] messageBytes = characteristic.getValue();
//            log("Read: " + StringUtils.byteArrayInHexFormat(messageBytes));
            String message = StringUtils.stringFromBytes(messageBytes);
            if (message == null) {
//                logError("Unable to convert bytes to string");
                return;
            }

//            log("Received message: " + message);
        }
    }

    public void setConnected(boolean connected) {
        mConnected = connected;
    }

    private void sendMessage() {


        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = BluetoothUtils.findEchoCharacteristic(bluetoothGatt);
        if (characteristic == null) {
            return;
        }

        String message = "2";

        byte[] messageBytes = StringUtils.bytesFromString(message);
        if (messageBytes.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        characteristic.setValue(messageBytes);
        boolean success = bluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        if (success) {
//            log("Wrote: " + StringUtils.byteArrayInHexFormat(messageBytes));
        } else {
//            logError("Failed to write data");
        }
    }

    public void initializeEcho() {
        mEchoInitialized = true;
    }

    private class BtleScanCallback extends ScanCallback {

        private Map<String, BluetoothDevice> mScanResults;

        BtleScanCallback(Map<String, BluetoothDevice> scanResults) {
            mScanResults = scanResults;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            addScanResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                addScanResult(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        }

        private void addScanResult(ScanResult result) {
            BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
            String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
            mScanResults.put(deviceAddress, device);
        }
    }

    public void disconnectGattServer() {
        mConnected = false;
        mEchoInitialized = false;
        if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
            bluetoothGatt.disconnect();
            bluetoothGatt.close();
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Do you get any error messages while connecting?

Comment: There aren't error but I don't understand why after a few seconds the status changes to "disconnected"

Comment: Are you getting into BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED at all?

Comment: Yes, after a few seconds it becomes "disconnected"

Comment: SO you can connect, but your BLE device disconnects after a few seconds. Have you tried using a generic BLE scanner app such as nRF Connect to test the connection? Maybe your BLE device (what kind of device is it?) closes the connection if you do not take some kind of action. You don't do anything after a successful connection

Comment: I think you are right but how do i send it a configuration byte right after i connect?

Comment: This depends on your device. What kind of device is it? Is it a custom device you have control over?

Comment: Bluetooth is we Proteus ii, do you have any idea?

Comment: This one? https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/PROTEUS-II How are you using it? How are you setting the services and characteristics? This should be added to the question, or better ask a new one

Comment: Yes, I use it in Peripheral only mode